# Artifactory has not been configured with remote repositories

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory Professional 5.9.0 rev 50900900

in web interface go to Admin->Repositories->Remote
(/artifactory/webapp/#/admin/repositories/remote)

and got error

> Artifactory has not been configured with remote repositories. To learn about remote repositories, refer to the JFrog Artifactory User Guide .

Button +New is inactive

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remote repos is not enabled immediately after you enter license key. After a week it start to work. May be reboot needed after license key was input.

Comment: Pro version support remote repositories from verious types. 
Where did you get this error?

Comment: I know what in documentation written what this functionality must to work in Pro version. But Pro version have no support. So I did not know why I got this error. The only answer I have got from jfrog by email is "feature is no enabled with the Pro version. It is only part of the Enterprise Edition of Artifactory."

Comment: I don't understand if you wish to resolve the issue you are experiencing or not... If you have a question about how to, place it here and the community will help.